# How to Set HTTP_HOST while Integration Testing via PHPUnit on multitenant Laravel app with different domain

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a multitenant application, in which every tenant has a specific domain or subdomain.
some of these tenants like the landlord have some particular features and tools.

I've managed to initialize HTTP_HOST in PHPUnit by adding the following line:
`<server name='HTTP_HOST' value='mydomain.local' />`
but doing this, I must manually change the HTTP_HOST every time and re-run the tests to cover all the scenarios.

is there any way to set this dynamically?

using `->withHeaders(['HTTP_HOST' => 'mydomain.local'])` won't work.

Comment: From what I remember, you must manually manipulate this value as you are currently doing

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Make sure to include the http scheme in the request uri.

```
$this->get('http://mydomain.local');
```

Explanation:

Behind the scenes `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` uses the `MakesHttpRequests` concern which filters the request uri through the
`MakesHttpRequests@prepareUrlForRequest` method which in turn passes the uri through the `url()` method.

This will prepend the value of `APP_URL` to make the uri absolute.

The url() method prepends the value of the APP_URL environment variable to make the URI absolute. For example, if you have APP_URL=http://localhost, the resulting URI in your specific case would be http://localhost/mydomain.local.

It's important to note that setting the host header or the HTTP_HOST server variable won't work as expected. This is because when the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request object is created, it overrides the HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME server variables based on the URI.

You can observe this behavior in the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create method:

```
$components = parse_url($uri);
if (isset($components['host'])) {
    $server['SERVER_NAME'] = $components['host'];
    $server['HTTP_HOST'] = $components['host'];
}
```

This behavior was tested and confirmed in Laravel 8.* with PHP 8.1.